# I want to disable password in Django's User table

Tags: django

I am currently using django to develop a web app.

I want to use an external Idaas and use the uuid issued by the external Idaas as the ID in the User table of django.

I don't need the password column in Django at that time, can I disable it?

I tried to create a new table without AbstractBaseUser and use the one without the password, but that didn't seem to work with Django's group feature.

Therefore.

・Use an external UUID as the key for the Django User table.
・I'm not sure how to do that.
・Use Django's standard group function.

I'd like to implement this in a way that satisfies the above three points.

If anyone knows more about this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You’ll want to read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @deceze

Thank you for your comment.

I already know about the custom user model.
On top of that, I initially created a User model without a password column, but in that case I could not use Django's standard feature groups and permission.

So I want to have a password column, but not require it.

Comment: It’s unclear why a (missing) password column would prevent you from using groups and permissions.

Comment: @deceze

To use permissions and groups, I think it needs to inherit PermissionsMixin when creating a custom user, such as class CustomUser( AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin ):.

Comment: PermissionsMixin must be used together with AbstractBaseUser to allow migration.
So when inheriting from AbstractBaseUser, I want to make sure that the password is not required.